# Haskell get elements from list through list of indices

Tags: haskell

I have a list of indexes and want to get a list filled with the values obtained by the indexes.

e.g.:

```
[1,2,3,4] `getAllOf` [1,3] --> [2,4]
```

What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Similar question here: [SO q44488080](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44488080/extract-from-a-list-elements-with-indexes-given-in-another-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using map should be the shortest solution for that.

This is the long version:

```
map (\x -> [1,2,3,4]!!x) [1,3]
```

you can simplify it by using:

```
map ([1,2,3,4]!!) [1,3]
```

is the short and clean way without lambda expression.

Answer (score 2):

It the list of *indices* is *sorted*, it is better to use recursion, since then we avoid enumerating multiples times over the list of values:

```
getAllOf :: [a] -> [Int] -> Maybe [a]
getAllOf = flip (go 0)
    where go _ [] _ = Just []
          go i (j:js) xs
              | j < i = Nothing
              | (y:ys) <- drop (j-i) xs = (y :) <$> go (j+1) js ys
              | otherwise = Nothing
```

This wraps the result in a `Just` if all indices are valid, and `Nothing` otherwise. For example:

```
Prelude> getAllOf [1..4] [1,3]
Just [2,4]
Prelude> getAllOf [1..4] [1,1]
Nothing
Prelude> getAllOf [1..4] [-1,2]
Nothing
Prelude> getAllOf [1..4] [15]
Nothing
Prelude> getAllOf [1..4] [0,1,2,3,4]
Nothing
Prelude> getAllOf [1..4] [0,1,2,3]
Just [1,2,3,4]
```