# How to pick multiple elements from a list in Haskell

Tags: loops, haskell, filter

In Haskell I know how I can pick *one* element  from a list by index :

```
head (drop idx myList)
```

But I have a list of indices `myIndices` (like `[1,3,5]`) and want to return a list of the elements in `myList` at the index positions in `myIndices`.

In a non-functional language I would build up the list over a loop, but how do I "build" the new list in Haskell? Can I use a filter?

Comment: `map (myList !!) myIndices`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the indices are not out of bound, you can go with

```hs
fmap (myList !!) myIndices
```

This requires that `myList` be indexable at every index in `myIndices`. If not, you get a runtime exception:

```hs
myList = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
myIndices = [1,2,3,10]
fmap (myList !!) myIndices
["b","c", "d","*** Exception: Prelude.!!: index too large
```

If you want to be robust in that respect, you can take a slightly different approach:

```hs
concat $ fmap (\i -> take 1 $ drop i $ myList) myIndices
```

Here each index `i` is turned into a list containing the one corresponding element from `myList` or an empty list if `myList` is not long enough; the resulting list of lists is flattened by `concat`.

The above can be written more compactly using the monadic bind operator `>>=`:

```hs
myIndices >>= (\i -> take 1 $ drop i $ myList)
```

---

The drawback of this approach is that it runs `take 1 $ drop i $ myList` for every single index, meaning that you traverse `myList` multiple times, thus giving a complexity *O(m*n)* for *m* indices and *n* elemnts in the list, whereas you could do it only once, in principle, as shown in the other answer. ([More details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44488234/5825294).) Whether such a complexity is acceptable, clearly depends how big *m*n* is.

Answer (score 4):

First let me add my standard remark that if you find yourself thinking about *indices in a list* you should reconsider your entire approach. It's better to think of lists as *streams* of values, where you never really care about absolute position but only about the values and possibly their relative order. If you really need indices, you should probably be using `Vector`s instead of lists.

But ok. If you would use a loop for some task in an imperative language, the obvious approach is always to use recursion in a functional language. Often it's not the most concise, reliable or efficient option, but it's what is always possible and you should certainly practice how to do it.

Basically you write a `go` function that has an `i` argument which is “incremented” for each recursive call much like the counter variable in a `for` loop, and the result is just a list which is build by purely prepending elements when `i` is in the indices list. Do implement this as an exercise.

But, yes, you could also use `filter` instead. The trick is that instead of manually maintaining a counter variable, you just add that information to the list as it were. In fact that's something often done even in Python

```
for i,x in enumerate(myList):
    ...
```

In Haskell, thanks to lazy evaluation, `enumerate` doesn't need any special iterable magic but can be expressed as a simple list zip: in fact the above Python loop could be written in e.g. the IO monad as

```
forM_ (zip [0..] myList) $ \(i,x) -> do
    ...
```

But here you don't really want to *loop* over the list, only, indeed, filter on it. Namely, you want to retain all the elements whose index is in the list of requested indices:

```
  [ x | (i,x) <- zip [0..] myList, i`elem`myIndices ]
```

Note that `elem` has bad performance though: it'll go through *all* the requested indices for all elements in `myList`, whereas if `myIndices` is sorted it would be enough to check only the head element. That's what you could do better in a recursive solution, or alternatively by using the `State` monad to pop the used indices.

But a rather nicer approach is to create a “masking” list from the list of indices, i.e. turning `[1,3,5]` into `[False, True, False, True, False, True]`. This could again be done with manual recursion, or with a trick like this:

```
indicesAsMask :: [Int]  -- Must be strictly sorted
              -> [Bool]
indicesAsMask ixs@(0:_) = True : do
   (il, ir) <- zip ixs $ tail ixs
   replicate (ir - il - 1) False ++ [True]
indicesAsMask ixs = False : tail (indicesAsMask $ 0:ixs)
```

Then you can simply zip your list together with the mask, and filter out those elements whose mask value is `True`.